# Googledocs spreadsheet script to open links from several fields on button click?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have several fields where I have several hyperlinks, lets say in fields `A1:A10`. I want to create Button A and Button B and put under it script so on Button A will open all links from range `A1:A5` and on Button B will open all links from range `A3:A10`.

I know I can open them with right mouse button click, but I want to assign specific range to specific button.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and a ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Putting buttons and on dialogs or sidebars is a much better idea?

Comment: Can you specify in details what you mean exactly?